# How to numerical evaluate trigonometric functions as a multiple of pi using the sympy package?

Tags: sympy

Is there a way to evaluate trigonometric functions as a multiple of pi using sympy? You can use the N function to get a numerical evaluation, but I'm searching for a function which will give me values like a * pi (a = constant).

Comment: Just divide whatever value you have by `pi`.

Answer (score 0):

SymPy already does that for inverse trigonometric functions. But to get a symbolic (as opposed to floating point) result, you need to provide symbolic (as opposed to floating point) input. Compare

```
>>> asin(1/2)     
0.523598775598299
>>> asin(Rational(1, 2))
pi/6
```

Here 1/2 produces a Python float 0.5, and the result is another Python float. But `Rational(1, 2)` constructs a SymPy object representing a rational number, and then evaluation is done symbolically.

More in [Python numbers vs. SymPy Numbers](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers)